# Environmental variables string value getting mangled on Windows

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, appium, tox

I'm trying to run Python tests with Tox on Windows with environmental variables like this:

```
set APP=c:\path\to\app\n-starting-folder\app.apk & tox -- report.xml tests/someTest.py
```

And in the `setUp()` method i retrieve the values from environmental variables:

```
capabilities = {}
capabilities['app'] = os.getenv('APP')
```

This gives me error that the path is wrong:

```
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Bad app: c:\path\to\app\n-starting-folder\app.apk . App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name. cause: Error: Using local app, but didn't end in .zip, .ipa or .apk
```

But if I put (exactly the same) path directly into the `setUp()` method as a raw string literal then no error:

```
capabilities['app']=r'c:\path\to\app\n-starting-folder\app.apk'
```

So my question is: why are values from environment variables getting mangled somehow? I suspect this is because there is an `"\n"` in the path, but I don't know how to escape it properly.

Comment: You have a trailing space in the environment variable. Use double quotes around the argument of the `set` command: `set "APP=c:\path\to\app\n-starting-folder\app.apk"`.

Comment: Also, your suspicion about `\n` is due to misunderstanding the difference between a string object and a source-code string literal. The characters `"\n"` in a string object have no inherent significance.

Comment: @eryksun it worked! I'd accept your answer if it wasn't a comment. Also thanks for pointing out the "\n" thing, I'll look into it